# ¿Problema al Desplazarse de un Textbox a un ListBox y viceversa con teclas de navegación del teclado?

Tags: c#, wpf

hasta ahora solo he logrado que funcione pero una sola vez , es decir desde el texbox le doy a la tecla DOWN y me pasa el foco al ListBox luego desde el este lo mismo pero con Up y funciona pero en el momento en que pulso por segunda vez la tecla DOWN desde el textbox ya no funciona .Lo hice manejando eventos pero creo que hay algo que claramente desconozco al respecto. Esto es todo el código es corto son solo 2 eventos , ya probé con varias combinaciones Preview Key Up Down etc ninguna me funciona la segunda vuelta desde el texbox al listBox. Aclaro estoy usando WPF. He probado poniendo e.handled=true al final del evento texbox,y en este caso selecciona el elemento indexado=0 pero nueva mente es como si se trabara en esa segunda vuelta.

```
private void TxtPractica_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                ListBoxPractica.Focus();
                ListBoxPractica.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
 }

 private void ListBoxPractica_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
            if (ListBoxPractica.SelectedIndex == 0 & e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                TxtPractica.Focus();
            }
 }
```

Comment: Eliminé mi respuesta, pues obviamente no responde a tu pregunta. Es cierto en WPF, no está disponible `KeyCode` ni lo está tampoco `Keys`, no obstante tu código debería funcionar, es un código muy elemental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He logrado solucionar el problema, aunque con trampa, espero te sirva:

```
private void TxtPractica_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        ListBoxPractica.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ListBoxPractica.Focus();
        TxtPractica.Focusable = false;
    }
}

private void ListBoxPractica_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBoxPractica.SelectedIndex == 0 & e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        TxtPractica.Focusable = true;
        ListBoxPractica.SelectedIndex = -1;
        TxtPractica.Focus();
    }
}
```

Como ves, manipulando la propiedad `Focusable` se puede lograr que el `Focus` se mueva en vez de atascarse en el `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que tenés que hacer conversión del valor de la tecla que se presiona.
Es tan simple como esto:

```
private void listBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Down))

                textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Up))

                listBox1.Focus();
        }
```

Acabo de probarlo y lo hace las veces que quieras, presionando Tecla Up o Tecla Down.

Comment: Pero eso es para WPF? o para Forms? Porque los Args de WPF son algo diferentes.

Comment: Probalo y decime si te funciona. A mi me funcionó con WPF.

Comment: Pues no.. no me reconoce PreviewKeyDownEventArgs ni KeyValue